# simple mapping of pandas series to 0 and 1s given threshold

Tags: python, pandas

I am sorry for asking such a simple question (yes I googled). Do I really require 2 steps to map a simple pandas series of float between 0 and 1s to 0 and 1s given a threshold. This is the reproducible example:

```
series = pd.Series([0.0, 0.3, 0.6, 1.0])
threshold = 0.5
print(series)

series[series > threshold] = 1.0
series[series <= threshold] = 0.0

print(series)
```

It works producing:

```
0    0.0
1    0.0
2    1.0
3    1.0
```

from:

```
0    0.0
1    0.3
2    0.6
3    1.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also apply a function on all elements using `map()` like

```
series = series.map(lambda x: 1.0 if x > threshold else 0.0)
```

Comment: I like that one as it is very expressive thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `>` operator.

```
series = (series > threshold).astype(int)
print(series)
```

Output:

```
0    0
1    0
2    1
3    1
dtype: int32
```

Comment: I like this too - sorry can only accept one

Answer (score 1):

I'd use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
np.where(series > threshold, 1, 0)
```

Comment: I use where for filtering - that's a good one too. Thanks. Just moving from R to Python